# Unable to download and share only 1st image from list of images in ViewPager [Strange Problem]

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

Hello I am facing Strange Problem I am making an gallery App which download images  using volley and showing them to Viewpager called SlideActivity everything is working properly. Problem:- when I try to Download & share 1st image from viewpager nothing happens but when swipe and go to 2nd image share and download is working for 2nd image and when i swipe back to 1st image now share and download works? This is what i have done till now want some advice on this issue.Thank you in Advance!

SlideActivity.Java

```
public class TrendingSlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL = "API";

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Context context = TrendingSlideActivity.this;
    private TrendingViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private int position;
    private int currentImage;
    private List<Trending> data;
    private ImageView shareIcon, shareImage, downloadImage;
    private int mAdCounter = 0;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trending_slide_activity);

            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
            shareIcon = findViewById(R.id.shareviewpager);
            downloadImage = findViewById(R.id.iv_download_slide);

            //final String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("filename");
            position = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("CODE", response);
                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    TrendingData users = gson.fromJson(response, TrendingData.class);
                    data = users.getData();
                    adapter = new TrendingViewPagerAdapter(context, data);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TrendingSlideActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(request);

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i) {

                    currentImage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                    final String fileName1 = data.get(currentImage).getFileName();
                    Toast.makeText(TrendingSlideActivity.this, "===========" + fileName1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    final String url2 = "API" + fileName1;

                    new LoadImage(TrendingSlideActivity.this).execute(url2);

                    shareIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onShareItem(shareImage);
                        }

                    });

                    downloadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            saveImageToGallery(shareImage);
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

                }
            });

    }

    private static class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {

        private WeakReference<TrendingSlideActivity> activityWeakReference;

        LoadImage(TrendingSlideActivity context) {
            activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... strings) {

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

            TrendingSlideActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity == null) return;

            activity.shareImage = new ImageView(activity);
            //Add image to ImageView
            activity.shareImage.setImageDrawable(result);

        }

    }


    public void onShareItem(View v) {
        // Get access to bitmap image from view
        // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri((ImageView) v);
        if (bmpUri != null) {
            // Construct a ShareIntent  with link to image
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            // Launch sharing dialog for image
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share TrendingData"));
        } else {
            // ...sharing failed, handle error
        }
    }

    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
        // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bmp;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // Store image to default external storage directory
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            // Use methods on Context to access package-specific directories on external storage.
            // This way, you don't need to request external read/write permission.
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            // **Warning:** This will fail for API >= 24, use a FileProvider as shown below instead.
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }

    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        String TAG = "Storage Permission";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void saveImageToGallery(ImageView iv) {
//        //to get the image from the ImageView (say iv)
//        BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
//        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();
        if (iv != null) {
            Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            } else {
            }

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                File dir = new File(sdCard, "/GalleryApp");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                try {
                    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    assert bmp != null;
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(TrendingSlideActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("TAAAAAAAAAAAAG", "onPictureTaken - wrote to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    String filePath = outFile.getPath();

                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{filePath}, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                }
                            });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(TrendingSlideActivity.this,"Please Wait Image is Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Reason why it isn't working is that you're setting image view inside `onPageSelected()` , and that method is not called for the first page, it's activated just after swiping.

Solution for this is move the entire code from `onPageSelected()` into function `selectImage(int position)` and call that function inside `onPageSelected()` as 
`selectImage(i)`.

This would be an improved version for code above, and will do the same as before, but now it's possible to set default state for the first view by calling 
`selectImage(0)` after `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)`

Comment: where i have to call this?

Comment: I'm on mobile, try below viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

Comment: app crashed => this warning on onPageselected Method. Method 'onPageSelected()' recurses infinitely and can only end by throwing an exception

Comment: As I said, I'm on mobile, and can't run the code, but I've explained what's the problem. 
Are you able to move the code from onPageSelected to a new function selectImage(int position).
and then in onPageSelected call selectImage(i); and after viewPager.setCurrentItem(position); call selectImage(0);

Comment: thank you it's working now and can u please look into share Method it takes few seconds to popup app windows in which we select different apps to share and sometimes it tells main thread is too busy?

Comment: please update your answer and also kindly explain me why it is working now?

Comment: Updated!
And regarding your issue with "main thread is too busy", you probably should move that functionality into AsyncTask.

Comment: kindly look share method is in AsyncTask only!